# Asp.net core + EF Code first, migration files in different project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

In my solution I want to use Asp.net core + EF Code first

I have 2 projects:

- CC.API
- CC.Infrastructure

In CC.API I have startup class and there is:

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), b => b.MigrationsAssembly("CC.Infrastructure")));
```

(Connection string is in appsettings.json)

As you can see I'm trying to keep migration files in different project - CC.Infrastructure.

Unfortunately whilst `Add-Migration Init` I receives an error: 
*Your target project 'PK.API' doesn't match your migrations assembly 'PK.Infrastructure'. Either change your target project or change your migrations assembly*

If I will change in startup `b => b.MigrationsAssembly("CC.API")` then everthing works fine, but files migration files will be in CC.API :/

Comment: In the package manager console, from the dropdown of default project, set it to `CC.Infrastructure`.

Answer (score 10):

This is/was a longstanding issue with EF Core. The solution *used* to be making your class library an executable (temporarily) and then run all EF operations against it.

With current tooling, you can just run `Add-Migration` while in the library folder; the only caveat is you need to set the `startup-project` flag to the actual executable's project.

So the command ends up being something like:

```
C:\CC.Infrastructure>dotnet ef migrations add NewMigration --startup-project ../CC.API/CC.API.csproj
```

Comment: @DiPix No dash; just a space you could also try running `dotnet restore` to make sure the SDK is in your current PATH

Comment: @DiPix I would make sure you have the .NET Core SDK installed and in your path; did the dotnet restore work?

Comment: In main folder this command restoring packages but in CC.Infrastrucuture: "Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore."

Comment: @DiPix Sounds ike CC.Infrastructure may not be a .NET standard/core project then?

Comment: It seems I don't have "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" but when I trying to add it then i receive an error: "`Package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet 1.0.1' has a package type 'DotnetCliTool' that is not supported by project 'CC.Infrastructure'.`" Maybe it's because this is ASP.NET Core on Framework?

Comment: I changed projects to Core. Still it doesn't work. Can you take a look on my github https://github.com/pklejnowski/pkproject ?

Answer (score 4):

As said by IvanZazz

1. Set UI/Web project as startup project
2. Set Infrastructure as default project in package manager console dropdown, **select the drop-down of default project for package manager console**, set it to CC.Infrastructure or the project which has DbContext class
3. Now run this command in package manage

> add-migration InitialIdentityModel

[image]

Comment: This is a very simple answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet` to your CC.Infrastructure project. Right click the project and select `Edit *.csproj`. Then, add the following:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

You can't add this from the Nuget package manager. It has to be added directly to the project.

Once you do that. You can run the command with the startup project set as CC.API. Go to the folder for your class library. The easiest way it to right click the project and `Open Folder in File Explorer`. Then, type `cmd` in the address bar of the `File Explorer` to open a command prompt in that folder.

Now use the following command to create the migration:

`dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -c DataContext --startup-project ../CC.API/CC.API.csproj`